# jQuery Add/Remove Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have a dilemna. I just learned how to use the add and remove class functions in jQuery but when you add a class it is not automatically removing the existing class. My problem is this. I have a button with a class on it that contains a background color. When I hover that button, I want the NEW class to take precedence over the old one, so in essence, I have to remove the old class. I just do not know where to begin. If I try to remove, add,remove, add, the hover doesnt seem to handle it all in one call. Can someone give me ideas?

I have two classes one is called '.ul.nav a' the other is '.work.

```
$('ul.nav a').hover(
  function () {     
    $(this).addClass('work');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('work');
  }
);
```

Here is the current class:

```
ul.nav a {
  display: block;
  background-color:#B2B2D9;
  margin-right:2%;
  margin-bottom:5%;
  margin-left:1%;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:3px #e6e6e6 ridge;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Which I would like to change to

```
.work {
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left 230px;
}
```

Comment: Is the pre-existing class always the same class?

Comment: Could you give an example of the HTML you'd like before/after a hover event?

Comment: No, I want the pre existing class to go away and be replaced with the new class. For instance, my old class has a bg color of blue, I want it changed to red, along with other features etc

Comment: You should probably be taking advantage of the "cascading" part of CSS. If you want a new class' properties to override an old class, make sure your new class (a) is [more specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and (b) is listed AFTER the old one in your CSS document.

Comment: I added the CSS you asked for

Comment: @RobertMailloux: Show your html code

Comment: look at [toggleClass]http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: It is specific and listed after, but that doesnt help in the JavaScript

Comment: toggle class was what I was thinking, BUT, it doesnt look like it would work with a hover in this case would it? The class is already on, when I hover that class needs to turn off, other class turn on, then on mouseOut, turn new class off and other one on

Comment: Blazemonger hit it on the head. THANKS!

Comment: `element.hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('work'); });`

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept your favorite answers to your questions, to encourage others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your CSS for `.work` to `ul.nav a.work` to make it [more specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Then it will override the old styles.

Comment: That nailed it! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd rethink your approach to use CSS ':hover' selector instead of JS. Something like

```
ul.nav a {
    background-color: blue;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know how to do it in CSS but I am just trying to teach myself jQuery. You are right though and I use that approach on my designs often. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'll just leave my answer here for someone looking for easier way then)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with your [CSS precedence](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Change your CSS to:

```
ul.nav a.work {
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left 230px;
}
```

Alternatively as this is just for hover, you can remove your javascript and change your CSS to:

```
ul.nav a:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left 230px;
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did it too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @Blazemonger implies in his comment, specificity and the CSS cascade are stopping the `.work` class from taking effect: Change your `.work` selector in the CSS to `ul.nav a.work` to ensure it will take precedence.

Comment: Yes that did it. Awesome help all!

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: let your styles be handled by CSS when possible. Instead of `.work` use this:

```
ul.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 230px;
}
```

And no need of javascript code.

Comment: Correct, but I am just trying to learn jQuery which is why I did this but THANK YOU as well